# MYSQL concat char to create table name with select

Tags: mysql

I tried to use such code

```
select
      price
from 
      (select concat("_",`id`) -- to set table name
as 
      dta 
from 
      druk 
where 
      date >= '2021-02-01' and date < '2021-03-01') d
```

If I put `*` instead `price` I get for example "_5438" - table name. One or more. In this way I can't get price.
I tried to use variables from examples I found, but some of them mysql do'es not recognize. What should I do to make proper, dynamic table name with concat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamic sql for this.

First you get the table nane into `@dta` and after that constructs the actual query which you run as [prepare statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html)

But this onlöy works, if your forwst select only goves back 1 eow as result, that is why it is `LIMIT 1`

```
SELECT concat("_",`id`) 
INTO 
      @dta 
FROM 
      druk 
WHERE 
      date >= '2021-02-01' AND `date` < '2021-03-01' LIMIT 1;   
 SET @sql := CONCAT('SELECT  price FROM  ',@dta );

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Still this does look like a poor design. to have many tables with the same design

For multiple ids you need a stored procedure, it can look like this).

But i didn_'t test it

> ```
> CREATE TABLE druk(`id` INT , `date` date)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO druk VALUES (1,now()),(2,now())
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE _1 (price DECIMAL(8,3))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO _1 VALUE (2.3),(4.6),(7.9)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE _2 (price  DECIMAL(8,3))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO _2 VALUE (0.3),(1.6),(3.9)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE createpricelist( IN _datefrom varchar(29),IN _dateto varchar(20)
> )
> BEGIN
>     DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
>     DECLARE _id VARCHAR(29);
>     DEClARE curid
>         CURSOR FOR 
>             SELECT concat("_",`id`) -- to set table name
>             FROM 
>                   druk 
>             WHERE 
>                   `date` >= _datefrom AND `date` < _dateto; 
>
>     -- declare NOT FOUND handler
>     DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
>         FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;
>     SET @datefrom :=  _datefrom;
>     SET @dateto := _dateto;
>     DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tableprice;
>     CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tableprice (price DECIMAL(8,2));
>     OPEN curid;
>
>     getprice: LOOP
>         FETCH curid INTO _id;
>         IF finished = 1 THEN 
>             LEAVE getprice;
>         END IF;
>         SET @od = _id;
>         SET @sql := CONCAT('INSERT INTO tableprice (price)   select  price from  ',_id);
>
>         PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
>         EXECUTE stmt;
>         DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
>
>     END LOOP getprice;
>     CLOSE curid;
> -- Diplay temporary table you can use it outside the procedure    
> SELECT * FROM tableprice;
> END
> ```

> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CALL createpricelist(NOW() -INTERVAL 1 DAY,NOW())
> ```
>
> ```
> | price |
> | ----: |
> |  2.30 |
> |  4.60 |
> |  7.90 |
> |  0.30 |
> |  1.60 |
> |  3.90 |
>
> ✓
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=119b7868e9506d4d30d8042db40be271)*

Comment: Select into variable works if there is only one row, so I think I have to create one select to find all tables, and create while loop for get data from these tables.

Comment: For multiple table you should use a procedure and a cursor and run the sae prepared statement

Comment: @KrzysztofKucner without data presemnted i have to make a complete test scenario, so please remeber in future provide always all tables with data, so i corrected, some small thngs